# How to use SpotifyWebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spotify

Excuse my English; I am Brazilian and I do not speak English. I have used Google Translator to translate my question into English.

I'm developing an application that uses the Spotify API, and my project is a C# MVC application. All the research I have done related to Spotify is using PHP, CURL examples and I am having trouble developing converting the examples in to C# code.

I managed to find a tutorial that is based on MVC but it is only contains partial information. My main issue is how to authenticate using OAuth.

If anyone has any information on how to proceed will be grateful.

Example using cURL:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQAI47GyJiPCgEl8X5ggPHxz10iVgtf8d86mR8RX_J9EwovDJDlL6qSYk_UeK3G4uXvfOEaf0jpohiL8iz6q1UJ4vO72yLX6u90XX-365DKUo4EYEpFfOtggcyitt03KeeclumTIOejf6Zr-9g"
```

Comment: What part of OAuth is it that you're finding troublesome to grasp? Did you read https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/?